# Best practice for different parts of an Angular (2) Webapp?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some quite general questions about Angular 2+ Webapps.

1. What is the best practice when you have, let's say, a publicly available info page, a authentication (login, signup, etc.) page and a protected page for singned users? --> Maybe separate Angular Apps (or maybe modules) or just using route guards?
2. When should I use more than 1 module in an Angular App?
3. Which plugin would you suggest for responsive tables which allow interaction with the user? (like sorting, Deleting a row, ... )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For more information on #2, check out the Angular docs here: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq

Comment: For more information on #3 checkout https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/ and https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/ its up to you which you want to use :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1 Guards with authentication systems (such as Json Web Tokens) will be enough to block routing to the core part of your application.
- Modules are made to split your application into logical parts. For example you will have a Dashboard module, an authentication module, etc... The aim is to provide services and communication inside modules generally.
- I use NG2 smartTable and it's quite efficient, but I guess it's oppinion based.